# MVC4 Invalid DateTime value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tried almost all what I read on the internet, on this website (the globlalization culture in the web.config, the DisplayFormat added in my model,...) but I didn't find my answer.

My web app allows the user to create persons by providing some information. One of these information is the Start date, which is a DateTime value. I'm using the jQuery UI date picker to allow the choice of the date through a calendar. As I choose my date (in fact, a date where the day is greater than 12), the application shows me an validation error message. For example, if I choose today's date, it will appear : The value '03/15/2013' is not valid for StartDate.

My View :

```
    @model BuSIMaterial.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            First name : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Last name : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            National number : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumNat, new { maxlength = 11 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumNat)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Start date : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new {@class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            End date : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Distance House - Work (km) : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseToWorkKilometers)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseToWorkKilometers)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Category : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Choose one ...")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_ProductPackageCategory) <a href = "../ProductPackageCategory/Create">Add a new category?</a>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Upgrade? : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Upgrade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Upgrade)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The Start Date in my Person Model :

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _StartDate;
        }
        set
        {
            OnStartDateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("StartDate");
            _StartDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("StartDate");
            OnStartDateChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.DateTime _StartDate;
    partial void OnStartDateChanging(global::System.DateTime value);
    partial void OnStartDateChanged();
```

Does anybody have a solution to deal with this problem?

Comment: Doesn't jQuery's datepicker return a string value?  How are you parsing it?

Comment: May be your code expects the date time in mm/dd/yyyy format where as date picker returns the date in dd/mm/yyyy format. So 15 is not a valid month number and it is giving the error.

Comment: @Forty-Two : To be honest, I followed a tutorial in order to implement the datepicker functionality so I didn't add anything but the code found on the tutorial

Comment: you are getting this error in the controller?

Comment: @Narendra : I also tried this solution but there, the app shows "The field must be a date" as validation error message.

Comment: When you debug and step through the code, what is the value of StartDate that is passed to the controller?

Comment: @Forty-Two : No, on the client-side. A validation error message appears then it is impossible for me to save a new person. Impossible to step into the Create Action because my error appears before.

Comment: If you look at your BuSIMaterial.Models.Person what are data annotations for the validation on the start date?

Comment: @robasaurus : I added it in my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you appear to be passing a raw entity to your view which is not a good idea. The correct approach in MVC is to create a **view model** which contains all the information your view needs, nothing more, nothing less.

Now to your problem:

> As I choose my date (**in fact, a date where the day is greater than 12**), the application shows me an validation error message

This gives me the impression this is a culture clash issue, your MVC app is expecting the date as `dd/mm/yyyy` but receiving it as `mm/dd/yyyy`. The default model binder in MVC will use the culture of the current thread - *if you're sure* that thread is using the correct culture then my guess would be it doesn't like the fact your only passing a `Date` instead of a `DateTime`, unlikely though.

Usually the best approach is to use a standardized date format which is culture-agnostic i.e. [UTC Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that way you avoid any conversion issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, could you give me a way/advice to do that?

Comment: @Traffy do what in particular? I made a few points in my answer.

Comment: In fact, when I format my date as dd/mm/yyyy it's not working. The error message has changed : "The field StartDate must be a date". I also tried in my web.config to specify the culture as auto, like this :

<globalization culture= "auto" uiculture = "auto"/>

Comment: @Traffy `auto` in the globalization would pick up the culture from the machine the site is running on and according to the [datepicker documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) the default format is `mm/dd/yy` - so straight off the bat the formatting isn't going to tie up. My suggestion would be to switch to a global date format which you can enforce on either side (like I mentioned UTC is the most common i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd`). It doesn't really matter what culture you want to use, the most important thing is your consistent with across your app.

Comment: Indeed, I precised that my date is a "yy-mm-dd" date format and it works. Thank you !

Comment: @Traffy my concern here though is your letting your client dictate the format rather than the server. It's probably best to decide on which format you intend to use and then have that passed down to your client via your view model and use that to configure your datepicker.

Comment: I had a similar issue I was trying to cheat and use a model directly with the view but this resulted in fields like the datetime enforcing the data format e.g. an SQL date which was me being lazy.  I created a proper View Model and then mapped the view model later in my service layer as I passed it to the repo for storage in the DB.